# Which US airlines have banned the new 'hoverboards' onboard?

Tags: luggage, airlines, prohibited-items

It seems that in the past few weeks, [several airlines have decided to ban hoverboards](http://www.forbes.com/sites/katiesola/2015/12/14/airlines-ban-hoverboards-for-their-tendency-to-spontaneously-ignite/) for fear of possible exploding/flammable batteries.

However, presumably the list will grow - and the article is not being updated - so is there a site/page/article elsewhere where people are tracking which airlines are banning them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qz.com has now started putting together a list](http://qz.com/565173/every-major-us-airlines-policy-on-bringing-a-hoverboard-with-you-on-your-flight/) with references for every major US airline's policy.

In general, airlines seem to be banning them, but where they're not it's based on the battery size, with some allowing batteries smaller than 100-160 watt hours.

Comment: Add [Flydubai](http://www.flydubai.com/), [Etihad](http://www.etihad.com/en-kw/before-you-fly/baggage-information/baggage-guide/), [Gulf Air](http://www.gulfair.com/baggage/prohibited-items) to that list (they also fly to the US - with the exception of Flydubai which may be used as a transit airline for US flights).

Comment: Shamelessly aiming for hats... :P